# Finding max number between two, which implementation to choose

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out, which implementation has edge over other while finding max number between two. As an example let's examine two implementation:

Implementation 1:

```
int findMax (int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b; 
}
```

// Assembly output: (gcc 11.1)

> ```
>     push    rbp
>     mov     rbp, rsp
>     mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
>     mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
>     mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
>     cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
>     jle     .L2
>     mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
>     jmp     .L4 .L2:
>     mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8] .L4:
>     pop     rbp
>     ret
> ```

Implementation 2:

```
int findMax(int a, int b)
{
    int diff, s, max;
    diff = a - b;
    s = (diff >> 31) & 1;
  
    max = a - (s * diff);
  
    return max;
}
```

// Assembly output: (gcc 11.1)

> ```
>     push    rbp
>     mov     rbp, rsp
>     mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
>     mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], esi
>     mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
>     sub     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
>     mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
>     mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
>     shr     eax, 31
>     mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
>     mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
>     imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
>     mov     edx, eax
>     mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
>     sub     eax, edx
>     mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax
>     mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
>     pop     rbp
>     ret
> ```

The second one produced more assembly instructions but first one has conditional jump. Just trying to understand if both are equally good.

Comment: With `-O3` GCC [produces](https://godbolt.org/z/46cWb69sd) just `cmp edi, esi; mov eax, esi; cmovge  eax, edi; ret`. No jumps.

Comment: Depends on what is "good". A question which can be answered like the choice of optimisation goals which you find in the tag info for the "optimization" tag. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/optimization/info My favorite is the last option. "teacher happiness".

Comment: If you're compiling with optimizations disabled, which you seem to be, comparing assembler output like that is meaningless.

Answer (score 5):

First you need to turn on compiler optimizations (I used `-O2` for the following). And you should compare to `std::max`. Then this:

```
#include <algorithm>

int findMax (int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b; 
}

int findMax2(int a, int b)
{
    int diff, s, max;
    diff = a - b;
    s = (diff >> 31) & 1;
  
    max = a - (s * diff);
  
    return max;
}

int findMax3(int a,int b){
    return std::max(a,b);
}
```

[results in](https://godbolt.org/z/E3P7oY6f6):

```
findMax(int, int):
        cmp     edi, esi
        mov     eax, esi
        cmovge  eax, edi
        ret
findMax2(int, int):
        mov     ecx, edi
        mov     eax, edi
        sub     ecx, esi
        mov     edx, ecx
        shr     edx, 31
        imul    edx, ecx
        sub     eax, edx
        ret
findMax3(int, int):
        cmp     edi, esi
        mov     eax, esi
        cmovge  eax, edi
        ret
```

Your first version results in identical assembly as `std::max`, while your second variant is doing more. Actually when trying to optimize you need to specify what you optimize for. There are several options that typically require a trade-off to be made: Runtime, memory usage, size of executable, readability of code, etc. Typically you cannot get it all at once.

When in doubt, do not reinvent a wheel but use existing already optimzied `std::max`. And do not forget that code you write is not instructions for your CPU, rather it is a high level abstract description of what the program should do. Its the compilers job to figure out how that can be achieved best.

Last but not least, your second variant is actually broken. See example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8M44jqYTc) compiled with `-O2 -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow`, results in:

```
/app/example.cpp:13:10: runtime error: signed integer overflow: -2147483648 - 2147483647 cannot be represented in type 'int'
```

You should favor correctness over speed. The fastest code is not worth a thing when it is wrong. And because of that, readability is next on the list. Code that is difficult to read and understand is also difficult to proove correct. I was only able to spot the problem in your code with the help of the compiler, while `std::max(a,b)` is unlikely to cause undefined behavior (and even if it does, at least it isnt your fault ;).

Comment: @MdMufti you can use a wider type, or you can check that no overflow happens before. There are ways to fix it. My point was just that you tried to optimize, but in fact you turned it into something that is not functionally equivalent, thats not good optimization

Comment: Ok. In your link (https://godbolt.org/z/8M44jqYTc) what I see the subtraction is reported with integer overflow since INT_MIN is getting subtracted by INT_MAX. That's ok since check not done for overflow. What I am looking for in a permissible range, if overflow isn't happening (let's put check there since just a sample code without boundary check) which one has edge over other.

Comment: @MdMufti no it is not ok. Why do you think so? I want to compute the maximum value between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, with your code I cannot do that without invoking UB. Why delete comments? My replies are useless without context

Comment: @largest_prime_is463035818, Thank your for your help! I understood your point about INT ranges. In my scenario data is in the range of hundred and std::max() is not an option since will be using in C too. Accidentally it got deleted. I am still struggling with editor.

Comment: @MdMufti I just got to know that C has `fmax` but nothing for integers. Funny how different the two languages are, if you just look at the details :)

Answer (score 3):

For two `int`s, you can compute `max(a, b)` without branching using a technique you probably learnt at school:

```
a ^ ((a ^ b) & -(a < b));
```

But no sane person would write this in their code. Always use `std::max` and trust the compiler to pick the best way. You may well find it adopts the above for `int` arguments with optimisations set appropriately. Although I conject that a compare and jump is probably the best way on the whole, even at the expense of a pipeline dump.

Using `std::max` gives the compiler the best optimisation hint.

Comment: *'no sane person would'* – well... I'd give it a try under some circumstances (machine with expensive branches, `std::max` not already optimised that way anway, profiling revealed std::max being a bottleneck). Am I insame???

Comment: @Aconcagua: But has any such expression survived in any of your production code? You may find on such an arch the best thing is monkey patching the standard library, or even hacking the source.

Comment: I wouldn't count on production code always being that clean. I've seen far worse, so we might be happy already if at least that line was correctly commented (what it does and why it's there).

Answer (score 3):

- Implementation 1 performs well on a **C**ISC **C**PU like a modern x64 AMD/Intel CPU.
- Implementation 2 performs well on a **R**ISC **G**PU like from nVIDIA or AMD Graphics.
- The term "performs well" is only significant in a tight loop.